# Akka does not see each other

Tags: java, akka, actor, akka-cluster

In Akka I add two different machines to the cluster. But there are some problems. If 2 machines stand up at the same time, the 2 side leaves as the leader and do not see each other.Or because of similar problems, they do not see each other. Do you know if he has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you configured the cluster, for example: 
1) hard-coded within seed-nodes list in your application.conf: should directly work if both machines can reach each other
2) discovery-mechanism by config, dns, tag (aws) (provided by lightbend): an example for config-based:

```
akka.management {
  contact-point-discovery {
    required-contact-point-nr = 2
    service-name = "MyApp"
    discovery-method = akka.discovery
  }
}
```

and an entry

```
akka.discovery {
  method = config
    config {
      class = "akka.discovery.config.ConfigSimpleServiceDiscovery"

      # Location of the services
      services-path = "akka.discovery.config.services"
      # hosts
      services {
        MyApp { //name should match the name set in akka-management.conf for service-name (https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-management/current/bootstrap/local-config.html)
          endpoints = [
            {
              host = "127.0.0.1"
            },
            {
              host = "127.0.0.2"
            }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where hosts would be those matching your machines.
Note that this requires "com.lightbend.akka.discovery" %% "akka-discovery-config" of the specific version in your build file.
With discovery, you also need to call AkkaManagement(actorSystem).start() and ClusterBootStrap(actorSystem).start() on each node's startup.

So really depends on your configuration.